# android view pager swipe animation

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager, swipe, android-pagetransformer

I am trying to do some animation in the page swipe in view pager by overriding the transformPage() method, such that when I swipe from right to left the new page (page coming from the right side) should appear below the previous page as soon as the animation starts and then the previous page should slide to the left side over the new page.
When I swipe from left to right the new page should directly slide over the previous page and covers it completely. But I am not able to achieve it. 
I have tried the following:-

```
if(position > 0 && position < 1)
{
    int pageWidth = page.getWidth();
    float translateValue = (-position * pageWidth);
    if(translateValue < pageWidth)
    {
        translationX = translateValue;
    }
    else
    {
        translationX = 0;
    }
}
else 
{
    alpha = 1;
    scale = 1;
    translationX = 0;
}
```

Please provide some suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this library. https://github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms

Comment: Not sure exactly the effect you are describing -- Something like this -- https://medium.com/@BashaChris/the-android-viewpager-has-become-a-fairly-popular-component-among-android-apps-its-simple-6bca403b16d4

Comment: A similar animation can be viewed in the Play Music app in Android 5.0 smartphones. On the play screen when you swipe from right to left the new page appears below the present page and for left to right swipe the new page appears/slides above/over the present page.

Answer (score 0):

This should work like you want, you just have to put it in your PagerTransformer class:

```
private static final float MIN_SCALE_DEPTH = 0.75f;

 @Override
public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
    final float alpha;
    final float scale;
    final float translationX;


            if (position > 0 && position < 1) {
                alpha = (1 - position);
                scale = MIN_SCALE_DEPTH + (1 - MIN_SCALE_DEPTH) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
                translationX = (page.getWidth() * -position);
            } else {
                alpha = 1;
                scale = 1;
                translationX = 0;
            }

    page.setAlpha(alpha);
    page.setTranslationX(translationX);
    page.setScaleX(scale);
    page.setScaleY(scale);
```

Comment: I tried your code and the problem is same as mentioned in my comment above. Using above code also the right page always stays on the top of the left page and I just want the opposite.

Comment: I got the solution to the problem by changing the first parameter passed to setPageTransformer() method to "true" and using the transformer code posted by Michał Hawryszko . I have read the documentation related to this parameter but I am not getting how the drawing order changes the Z indices of the pages. Can somebody explain this ?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention about setting this parameter. According to documentation this parameter changes the page drawing order from first to last to last to first.